# Empty SPARQL Query Result

Tags: python, sparql, rdf, rdfs, rdflib

Trying to run a SPARQL query against a local ttl file.  I have done this successfully before, but not this one.  I suspect it has something to do with namespaces.

Tried printing out what the query was, and all I get is "rdflib.plugins.sparql.processor.SPARQLResult at 0x1fbe05d3400" so there IS somthing there.

Here is the ttl file

```
 # filename: ex050.ttl

 @prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> . 

 <http://www.learningsparql.com/ns/demo#i93234>
         foaf:nick "Dick" ;  
         foaf:givenname "Richard" ; 
         foaf:mbox "richard49@hotmail.com" ;
         foaf:surname "Mutt" ;
         foaf:workplaceHomepage <http://www.philamuseum.org/> ;
         foaf:aimChatID "bridesbachelor" .
```

And here is the python code firing off the SPARQL query

```
 filename = "C:/DataStuff/SemanticOntology/LearningSPARQLExamples/ex050.ttl" 
 import rdflib
 g = rdflib.Graph()

 result = g.parse(filename, format='ttl')
 query = """
 PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> 
 PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

 SELECT ?propertyLabel ?value 
 WHERE
 {
   ?s ?property ?value . 
   ?property rdfs:label ?propertyLabel . 
 }

 """

 results=g.query(query)
 print('Results!')
 for row in results:
     print(row)
```

I know it is something basic that I screwed up.  Please help!

Comment: Your properties do not have `rdfs:label`s. Comment out the second triple pattern or put it into `OPTIONAL {...}`

Comment: True. I mean this example data is very tiny, it's quite obvious. And SPARQL does nothing  than doing exact pattern (aka subgraph) matching. You can query only for something that explicitly exists. (or can be inferred, but that's a different story)

Comment: But isn't that the point of using the foaf namespace?  I am asking for the labels to the properties that are defined there.

Comment: what is with the FOAF namespace? You just used it in the URIs. What you mean is Linked Data dereferencing, not tool ever does this by default as it is obviously expensive to fetch data on demand from the web during query execution. What you could do is to load FOAF into your graph. As you did in your answer by the way.D:

Comment: So adding the URI doesn't actually mean I have access to it?  Its just a way of keeping names straight?  Then why all the hype about RDF?  If I need to use 10 different vocabularies, does that mean I have to go out - download each one and have a merged vocabulary file that will be out of date in a week?

Comment: K - I see that you can query against multiple SPARQL endpoints using a federated query which uses the SERVICE keyword - though I have no idea how/if this can be done using RDFLIB objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay - pouring over the RDFILB specs (https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/rdflib/4.2.1/rdflib.pdf), I discovered that you can parse multiple files/urls one after the other.  The result is a merged file.  So knowing that the foaf file I was interested in could be downloaded at 
http://www.xmlns.com/foaf/spec/index.rdf

I got the file, then altered the program to:

```
filename = "C:/DataStuff/SemanticOntology/LearningSPARQLExamples/ex050.ttl" 
filename2 = "C:/DataStuff/SemanticOntology/LearningSPARQLExamples/index.rdf"

g = rdflib.Graph()

g.parse(filename, format='ttl')
g.parse(filename2)
query = """
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> 
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?propertyLabel ?value 
WHERE
{
  ?s ?property ?value . 
  ?property rdfs:label ?propertyLabel . 
}

"""

results=g.query(query)
print('Results!')
for row in results:
    print(row)
```

Which then worked, printing out:

```
Results!
(rdflib.term.Literal('Given name'), rdflib.term.Literal('Richard'))
(rdflib.term.Literal('Surname'), rdflib.term.Literal('Mutt'))
(rdflib.term.Literal('AIM chat ID'), rdflib.term.Literal('bridesbachelor'))
(rdflib.term.Literal('personal mailbox'), rdflib.term.Literal('richard49@hotmail.com'))
(rdflib.term.Literal('workplace homepage'), rdflib.term.URIRef('http://www.philamuseum.org/'))
(rdflib.term.Literal('nickname'), rdflib.term.Literal('Dick'))
```

printing out the labels of all the human readable properties in my original data file, even though I didn't define those properties.

I imagine that the step of downloading the file could be skipped by directly using the URL in the second parse statement.  However I cannot do this as I am in a corporate environment and I don't see a way of using the parse statement with a proxy.